# iOS UIAlertView being shown more than once

Tags: ios, uialertview

Hi I have used the following function to call an alert view with a specific message. The NSLogs are being printed only once but alert view is called more than once.

I am using `UITabBarController` for any additional info.

```
- (void)showUIAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    NSLog(@"showUIAlertWithMessage called");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something went wrong!"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Is there another place where an `[alert show]` is being called? There could be another one in other of the delegate methods.  I would insert break points on the NSLog line, the `[alert show]` line and any other line in the class containing `[alert show]` and just double check that everything is getting called the right number of times.

Comment: There are three UITabBarController and each has this same function and [alert show] is written only once..

Comment: The problem is resolved now. Actually I was using NSNotificationCenter that was triggering this method more than once. So I removed myself as an observer for the notification name.